# how to find code generated object in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to find my button which i generated using this code:

```
 void OnGUI(){
     GUI.Button (new Rect (Screen.width * .25f, Screen.height * .3f, Screen.width * .5f, 50f), "Start     Game"); 
 }
```

I found this code where i could find the gameobject.

```
 GameObject.Find ("")
```

but then i need some id or something. Can i set id of the button that i created or can i find that object in some other way?

Or is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to find it, you already have it the moment you created it. You are using the `OnGUI()` function to draw it so that is were it will exist.

If you want to use the button, for example to detect a click all you do is put it in an `if`

```
 void OnGUI()
 {
     if(GUI.Button (new Rect (Screen.width * .25f, Screen.height * .3f, Screen.width * .5f, 50f), "Start     Game"))
         Debug.Log("I was clicked");
 }
```